# Why does this multithreaded program output 100 instead of the expected 200?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning multithreading. Can anyone tell why here the output is always 100, even though there are two threads which are doing 100 increments?

```
public class App {    
    public static int counter = 0;

    public static void process() {    
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                    ++counter;
                }    
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                    ++counter;
                }    
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        process();
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

The output is 100.

Answer (score 12):

You're only *starting* the threads, not waiting for them to complete before you print the result. When I run your code, the output is 0, not 100.

You can wait for the threads with

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

(at the end of the `process()` method). When I add those, I get 200 as output. (Note that `Thread.join()` throws an `InterruptedException`, so you have to catch or declare this exception.)

But I'm 'lucky' to get 200 as output, since the actual behaviour is undefined as Stephen C notes. The reason why is one of the main pitfalls of multithreading: your code is not *thread safe*.

Basically: `++counter` is shorthand for

1. read the value of `counter`
2. add 1
3. write the value of `counter`

If thread B does step 1 while thread A hasn't finished step 3 yet, it will try to write the same result as thread A, so you'll miss an increment.

One of the ways to solve this is using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), e.g.

```
public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

...

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                counter.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

> Can anyone tell why here the output is always 100, even though there are two threads which are doing 100 increments?

The reason is that you have two threads writing a shared variable and a third reading, all without any synchronization.  According to the Java Memory Model, this means that the actual behavior of your example is unspecified.

In reality, your `main` thread is (probably) printing the output before the second thread starts.  (And apparently on some platforms, it prints it before the first one starts.  Or maybe, it is seeing a stale value for `counter`.  It is a bit hard to tell.  But this is all within the meaning of *unspecified*)

Apparently, adding `join` calls before printing the results *appears* to fix the problem, but I think that is really by luck<sup>1</sup>.  If you changed 100 to a large enough number, I suspect that you would find that incorrect `counter` values would be printed once again.

Another answer suggests using `volatile`.  This isn't a solution.  While a read operation following a write operation on a `volatile` is guaranteed to give the latest value written, that value may be a value written by another thread.  In fact the `counter++` expression is an atomic read followed by an atomic write ... but the sequence is not always atomic. If two or more threads do this simultaneously on the same variable, they are liable to lose increments.

The correct solutions to this are to either using an `AtomicInteger`, or to perform the `counter++` operations inside a `synchronized` block; e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        synchronized(App.class) {
            ++counter;
        }
    }
```

Then it makes no difference that the two threads may or may not be executed in parallel.

---

<sup>1 - What I think happens is that the first thread finishes before the second thread starts.  Starting a new thread takes a significant length of time.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In Your case, There are three threads are going to execute: one main, thread1 and thread2. All these three threads are not synchronised and in this case Poor counter variable behaviour will not be specific and particular.
These kind of Problem called as [Race Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

`Case1:` If i add only one simple print statement before counter print like:

```
process();
    System.out.println("counter value:");
    System.out.println(counter);
```

in this situation scenario will be different. and there are lot more..
So in these type of cases, according to your requirement modification will happen.

1. If you want to execute one thread at time go for Thread join like:

   thread1.join();

   thread2.join();

join() is a Thread class method and non static method so it will always apply on thread object so apply join after thread start.

If you want to read about Multi threading in java please follow; https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032e/index.html

Comment: This "answer" does not answer the question. You told the OP to use `join()`, which is good, but you did not say where to use it or why.

Comment: When you start a thread then you can apply join(). Join() method is not an static method and it is an thread class method, so it can only apply by thread object.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the result before threads are done.

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();


try{
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
}
catch(InterruptedException e){}
```

And make `counter` variable `volatile`.

Comment: No! `volatile` is not enough because `++counter` is _not_ an atomic operation.  The only thing that `volatile` guarantees is that updates made by thread A before it updated the counter will become visible to thread B by the time thread B is able to see the update of the counter itself.  It does _not_ prevent, for example, both thread A and thread B simultaneously looking at the counter, both seeing its value to be 42, and both storing 43 back in to it (i.e., one increment lost.) The OP should either use an `AtomicInteger` operation for that (advanced topic), or use locking (first baby step.)